# difference between "color" and "color-index" in media query

Tags: css, media-queries

What is the difference between these to media query features

```
@media all and (color-index) { } 

@media (max-color:4) { }
```

Comment: Did you check the docs? ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#color-index

Comment: I voted to close as the answer exist in the docs, and a simple net search would have given the answer.